# SQL Server events on insert

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server. I want to raise an event when client inserts any row in order to copy that row to another table with more columns.

I have to do that in SQL Server just after insert. Is this possible? And if it is... how?

I need something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON (INSERT ROW?)
    DO
      TODO...
```

But I don't know if there are any event on insert and I don´t know where does the code go.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have another problem added. The tables are in different databases. I'm trying to implement this trigger:

```
    USE [DB1]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER_NAME] 
   ON  [dbo].[TABLE_TRIGGERED]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO DB2.[dbo].[FINAL_TABLE] 
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE COL1= 'Stuff' AND COL2= 'Stuff' AND COL3=
    (
        SELECT MAX(COL3)+1
        FROM DB2[dbo].[FINAL_TABLE]
    )

END
```

And it can't access to COL1, COL2 and COL3. Is my sintax right?

Comment: I think an `insert` trigger is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look some info about triggers.

Comment: Correct syntax for WHERE criteria is : SELECT MAX(COL3)+1 FROM DB2.[dbo].[FINAL_TABLE]    You have done it correct in INSERT INTO part

Comment: SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
    WHERE COL1= 'Stuff' AND COL2= 'Stuff'    these COL1 and COL2 columns are from INSERTED table not from the target Final_Table. You filter data of FROM clause.

Comment: ops you're right. But a part of that I still having a problem with uncorresponding table definition with this (more simple) query:

USE [DB1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [TRIGGER_NAME] 
   ON  [DB1].[dbo].[TABLE_OF_DB1]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [BD2].[dbo].[TABLE OF BD2] 
 SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED
END

Comment: ops it works. I forget one column... Thanks for all. I didn´t know how the triggers works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an [SQL After Insert trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/log-price-changes-using-sql-server-trigger-in-sql-server.aspx), you can handle it
If this is your first time with triggers, take care of set based coding.
If you miss it, on INSERT statements with multiple rows you might get unexpected results. So keep away using variables in the trigger code, think always set based using the Inserted and Deleted tables special to triggers
You can check the referred tutorial

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna that tutorial now.